# How to manage Admin and Users on same browser in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can I manage Admin and Users on same browser in laravel? I'm unable to differentiate admin and user session.

How to differentiate admin's session to user's session?

Comment: why do you want to set two sessions at the same time?

Comment: make separate route groups for both admin & user

Comment: This question is too broad, what have you tried? Is there a definite Admin user, or will they be separated by roles and permissions? I can think of more than 10 different ways to approach depending on what you need.

Comment: If you're using sessions, the user's session is shared across all tabs. You can start a separate session by using a different browser or an incognito window in the same browser. If you use something like JWT/Passport, different tabs *may* be able to have different sessions, depending on how they're stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin login in New window.
And you can also use user login in Incognito window using Ctrl + Shift + N in Same browser.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is adding an is_admin attribute to the users table (providing you store both in one table). You can then add multiple if statements to show necessary links and views. Hope this helps.